# Override a Function

Tags: vba, excel

The following "aMacro" returns the error "Ambiguous name Detected"  I understand why.  Anybody know a way to override the first definition and and only use the definition inside of the function so that aFunction will return x - y  ?

Besides changing the name.

```
Function aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer

    aFunction = x + y

End Function



Sub aMacro()

    Function aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
        aFunction = x - y
    End Function
    MsgBox aFunction(4, 3)

End Function
```

Comment: you can't override function- you need to either change first one or create new one, like `Function bFunction`.

Comment: Even if you change the name of the 2nd `Function` (and the return code within it) to "bFunction" this won't compile, because you have a function inside a `Subroutine`. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A function can be `Private` or `Public`, but the scope is always the whole module.

Comment: The scope of `Private` functions / subs is the whole module. The scope of `Public` functions / subs is the whole project (or even all open projects, since you can invoke a `Public` function / sub defined in project A from project B)

Comment: @Barranka: Yes, kinda. The scope is the whole project in functions defined in code modules, not in class or worksheet modules. And a function is visible across projects only if you include them as references. I gave a quick description because the questions asks how to reduce the scope, not how to enlarge it.

Answer (score 0):

This can simulate "override function" with 4 class modules:
Functions, IFunction, FunctionAdd, FunctionSubtract.

class module Functions:

```
Function aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    aFunction = x + y
End Function
```

interface IFunctions:

```
Function aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

class module FunctionAdd:

```
Implements IFunctions

Private mFunctions As Functions

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mFunctions = New Functions
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mFunctions = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IFunctions_aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    IFunctions_aFunction = mFunctions.aFunction(x, y) ' Uses the standard aFunction
End Function
```

Class module FunctionSubtract:

```
Implements IFunctions

Private mFunctions As Functions

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mFunctions = New Functions
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mFunctions = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IFunctions_aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    IFunctions_aFunction = x - y ' Override aFunction, subtract values
End Function
```

You can test this with this:

```
Dim f As IFunctions
Set f = New FunctionAdd: Debug.Print f.aFunction(1, 2)
Set f = New FunctionSubtract: Debug.Print f.aFunction(1, 2)
```

Of course this is tedious for one function.
I could be useful is you have a lot of functions to override in many classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the Optional value in the function. If the optional value isnt included in the call then it wont be references in the function.

```
Function aFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer, Optional override As Boolean) As Integer
    If Not override Then
        aFunction = x + y
    Else
        aFunction = x - y
    End If
End Function
Sub aMacro()
    MsgBox aFunction(4, 3)
    MsgBox aFunction(4, 3, True)
End Sub
```