# How to get intellisense with VBA overriding

Tags: vba, oop

## Example of what I'm trying to do

In MS Office it is possible to get intellisense for **both** of these things: `Application.Documents(1).` and  `Application.Documents.`

I'm trying to do the same for my own classes, I think this is called overriding?

### I'm getting stuck with the intellisense...

The following images show what I'm trying to achieve for my own classes (i.e. get intellisense for both  `Things.` and `Things(i).` ...):

**Image 1** *(below)* shows intellisense for the documents collection, e.g. `.count` property.

[image: intellisense for the documents collection]

**Image 2**  *(below)* shows intellisense for a document, it's completely different.
[image: intellisense for a document]

## What I have

I started out by modifying code from this answer (a 'calculator' which provided the basic structure): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704040/3451115

The modified code has 2 new classes, they are the 'objects to be returned' (instead of a calculated value from the original code):

- a collection class (`cThings`)
- an object class (`oThing`)

So, just like for `.Documents`, I want to be able to:

`Things.` or `Things(i).` and get intellisense...

I figured that adding an index `(i)` *i.e. `item:=index`* MUST be optional so I made the parameter optional.

Although when working with the Documents collection I noticed that, when opening the parenthesis `(...`, the item parameter is NOT enclosed by [square brackets] *(which as far as I know normally indicates optional)*.

**Question:** Is it possible? How can it be achieved?

---

### Here are the classes & modules:

Standard module for testing *(works but does NOT have intellisense)*:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "overrideExample"
Sub test()
    Dim bar As IFoo

    Set bar = New cFoo
    Debug.Print bar.Things.count     ' No intellisense for count

    Set bar = New oFoo
    Debug.Print bar.Things(1).name   ' No intellisense for name

End Sub
```

Interface, IFoo

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IFoo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Function Things(Optional index As Integer) As Object
End Function
```

Collection of Foo, cFoo

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "cFoo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Implements IFoo

Private mFunctions As Foo

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mFunctions = New Foo
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mFunctions = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IFoo_Things(Optional x As Integer) As Object
    Set IFoo_Things = mFunctions.Things ' Uses the standard aFunction
End Function
```

Object of Foo, oFoo

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "oFoo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Implements IFoo

Private mFunctions As Foo

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mFunctions = New Foo
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mFunctions = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IFoo_Things(Optional x As Integer) As Object
    Dim tempThing As oThing
    Set tempThing = New oThing
    tempThing.name = "FooBar"
    Set IFoo_Things = tempThing
End Function
```

Collection of Things, cThings

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "cThings"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Type TThings
    m_objmyThings As Collection
End Type

Private this As TThings

Public Function count() As Integer
    count = this.m_objmyThings.count
End Function

Public Property Get myThings() As Collection
    Set myThings = this.m_objmyThings
End Property

Public Property Set myThings(ByVal objNewValue As Collection)
    Set this.m_objmyThings = objNewValue
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set this.m_objmyThings = New Collection
End Sub
```

Object of Thing, oThing

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "oThing"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Type TThing
    m_sName As String
End Type

Private this As TThing

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = this.m_sName
End Property

Public Property Let name(ByVal sNewValue As String)
    this.m_sName = sNewValue
End Property
```

Object Foo, Foo

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Foo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Function Things(Optional x As Integer) As cThings
    Set Things = New cThings
End Function
```

Comment: If the property `Things` has `Object` as return type then Intellisense isn't going to be much use: it has no way to predict what will be contained in Collection wrapped by objects of that type.  You get Intellisense in part by having Properties with *specific* return types.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I'm starting to realise that.  I don't think there is a way, about to post an answer explaining...

Comment: `Documents(i)` is just a shortcut to the default property of Documents, which is `Documents.Items` whose return type id `Document`. But that has nothing to do with why you don't see intellisense, which is, as you've pointed out yourself, because you are returning the type `Object`. Why not return a concrete type?

Comment: @andrew ... but how? `Documents(i)` is a document whereas `Documents` is a document collection. I did play around with the default member, but to no avail.

Comment: @SlowLearner - Because Documents(i) is not the same property as Documents. Documents(i) is actually Documents.Item(i). Hence no need to have two members with the same name ("overloading"). I've shown an example implementation as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense requires a return type other than `Object` - you need to return your `oThing` type.

There are various ways to get what you want and various questions about how you want to do it - namely - do you want to hide the internal Collection in the `cThings` class, or are you wanting to expose it like you do in your example (which IMO seems bad).

I'll just answer the direct questions you have:

> How do I get intellisense for Count on `bar.Things.count`

Answer: you set the return type on bar.Things to something. It could be your `cThings` collection type, or it could be the Collection you have inside the `cThings` collection type (IMO it is bad to return the internal Collection object).

So type `Foo` needs a `Things` property that returns a `cThings`:

```
Property Get Things() As cThings
    Set Things = myThings
End Property
```

Also, `cThings` needs a `Count` property. You can just pass-through the internal collection's Count property:

```
Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = myInternalCollection.Count
End Property
```

> How do I get intellisense for Name on `bar.Things(1).name`

Answer: firstly, the MSWord example of `Documents(i)` is equivalent to `Documents.Item(i)` where `Item` is the default property of `Documents` which takes an index. Creating a default property is a pain in VBA. You have to edit the module as a text file and import it. Sucks.

If you were to settle for having intellisense for Name on `bar.Things.Item(1).name` and forego the shortcut syntax for the default property then you can just add the following to `cThings`:

```
Property Get Item(index) As oThing
    Set Items = myInternalCollection.Item(index)
End Property
```

Now you'll have intellisense on `bar.Things.Item(1).name`.

However, if you really want `bar.Things(1)` to work then you need to do this:

Export your module and insert an attribute into the Item property:

```
Property Get Item(index) As oThing
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Items = myInternalCollection.Item(index)
End Property
```

Then, import it back.

Now, `bar.Things(1)` will translate to `bar.Things.Item(1)` which will return an item and be shown in intellisense.

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a good look at this and get back to you :)

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** ***It is possible*** I was just going about it the wrong way. @andrew provided a way of setting things up that works exactly the way I wanted as per the images in the question. Nevertheless, this (incorrect) answer provides some useful background info and context to others who might also be struggling with this...

---

### I think it is <s>not</s> possible *(see the accepted answer)*

Reading here: https://hammondmason.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/object-oriented-vba-overloading/ states that VBA is a dynamically typed language and to properly support overloading it would need to be statically typed, i.e. enforce more explicit variable types.

And, as mentioned by @TimWilliams - returning an object will basically prevent intellisense...

That said, I *think* I improved *(simplified)* the overloading example (but still no intellisense):

```
Sub test()

    Dim bar As IFoo

    Set bar = New cFoo
    Debug.Print bar.things.Count
    Debug.Print bar.things(1).name
    Set bar = Nothing

End Sub
```

Revised cFoo:

```
Public Property Get things(Optional x As Integer) As Object
        Set things = IFoo_Things
End Property

Private Function IFoo_Things(Optional x As Integer = -1) As Object
    Select Case x

        Case -1 ' Return Collection of Things
            Set IFoo_Things = mFunctions.things

        Case Else ' Return specific Thing
            Dim tempThing As oThing
            Set tempThing = New oThing
            tempThing.name = "FooBar"
            Set IFoo_Things = tempThing
    End Select
End Function
```